# Max supported external display resolution @60z for 2012 Macbook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I have a mid-2012 13" Macbook Air with Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

My monitor died recently so I'm in the market for a new one, and I would like to know the maximum supported resolution for external displays @ 60hz refresh rate on this model?

The Apple info page here
https://support.apple.com/kb/sp670?locale=en_GB
...states that max res is 2560x1600 but it doesn't state the refresh rate.

I don't want to go for that if only 30hz is supported.

The canonical question for Macbook display resolution answers is:
[MacBook Pro - how many displays, what resolution/frequency?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335322/macbook-pro-how-many-displays-what-resolution-frequency)

This provides a link to [EveryMac website](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/) which has more detailed specs info than provided by Apple.

However when I lookup my MBA on EveryMac I only find the following info:

> **2nd Display Support:** "Dual/Mirroring*
>   **2nd Max. Resolution:**  2560x1600 (x2)
>   **Details:**
>   *Although Apple makes no mention of it, third-parties have discovered that this model can simultaneously support two external displays up to
>   2560x1600 "daisy chained" via Thunderbolt."

As with the official Apple specs, this does not give the refresh rate supported at 2560x1600.

Commenters have suggested that 2560x1600 is only supported @ 30hz... in which case my question still stands: what is the max resolution supported @ 60hz (for my specific model of Macbook)?

Comment: @Tetsujin that question is completely unrelated to what I am asking

Comment: @Allan that comes very close to answering it, but ultimately the EveryMac Ultimate Lookup does not specify the refresh rate either. It says _"Dual/Mirroring* 2nd Max. Resolution: 2560x1600 (x2) Details: *Although Apple makes no mention of it, third-parties have discovered that this model can simultaneously support two external displays up to 2560x1600 "daisy chained" via Thunderbolt."_ So that's interesting, but does not confirm if either of those displays were operating at 60hz

Comment: The Intel HD 4000 uses DisplayPort 1.1 and HDMI 1.4 standards.  Both of which are limited to 30Hz.  It's not an Apple issue but an HD 4000 issue.  You need either DP 1.2 or HDMI 2.0.  (IMO) I would avoid any MBP without a discrete GPU.

Comment: @Allan the question is still what is the max resolution for external display @ 60hz, for my MBA 2012

Comment: You can't do 60Hz and the Max resolution is answered by the dupe.

Comment: I can do 60hz, I'm doing 1900x1200 @60hz on my current monitor. The question is if there is any higher res supported at that refresh

Comment: Sorry, was working on my phone & managed to post completely the wrong link. Will fix.

Comment: Let's close this temporary to the canonical question that explains the max res on one of the answers. If we collectively (or someone) can edit this to incorporate the link to the canonical question and then ask one quick new question that's not evident from the canonical question - I'd support reopening this. Based on the comments - it's not entirely clear this is answerable as is.

Comment: @bmike I have edited my question with a link to the canonical one and details of why my specific query is not answered there

Comment: here is some info which appears to contradict @Allan's comment re 30hz: https://communities.intel.com/message/371993#371993 namely that Intel HD 4000 supports 2560x1600@60hz over DisplayPort 1.1.  The 30hz limitation is for HDMI only

Comment: When you say "support" that will get people to answer only Apple supports this product, so Apple says 30 Hz (or whatever their KB says today) so you might acknowledge that often the hardware runs past the specifications and you want people to report if they can in the field get a higher refresh rate than what is officially supported.