# Super Ultra-Wide 32:9 at 5120×1440 @ 60hz on a MacBook Pro 15-inch, Mid 2014 with GeForce GT750M

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, resolution, thunderbolt-display

Hardware:

- [MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) 16GB RAM with NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2GB](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP704?locale=en_GB)
- [Samsung C49RG90 49-inch Super Ultrawide 1440p](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-C49RG90-49-inch-Ultrawide-Monitor/dp/B07NL27TCK/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=32%3A9%201440p&qid=1589478341&sr=8-5)
- Thunderbolt to DisplayPort cable

The [official spec](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP704?locale=en_GB) unfortunately doesn't have any reliable information about supported resolutions in external monitors because of this:

- I can currently run 3840x2160@60hz.
- I want to run 5120×1440@60hz, which is ~10% less pixels.
- Official spec says maximum is 2560x1600, which is literally **half** of my current resolution.

Since this type of monitor is quite new, I only see articles/videos using newer MacBooks.

Has anyone tried this yet or do you know how I could figure this out before actually buying the monitor?

Comment: The information you say doesn't exist is right there in your link. "Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on up to two external displays, both at millions of colors" So, no, it won't work, unless it can be supported at two displays.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacBook \[Pro\] - how many displays, what resolution/frequency?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335322/macbook-pro-how-many-displays-what-resolution-frequency)

Comment: @Tetsujin, not really. As mentioned in the question, I can run 4k@60hz, which is higher than what's state by the official spec. Also there's no information about refresh rate.