# 4K monitor with MacBook Pro 2012 Non-retina not working well in 2K resolution

Tags: macbook-pro, display

- LG 4K monitor 27 inch (lg-27UK650)
- Macbook pro 2012 Non Retina 16gb RAM/256 GB SSD

Using 4K monitor with mini DisplayPort. Display works randomly, and sometime stops working while in use. Monitor keeps displaying no signal. I am using external monitor in 2K resolution. Earlier I used to connect full HD monitor on mini DisplayPort and never had this kind of issue.

Monitor works fine with my other laptop. Thinkpad x260 over same mini display port.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacBook \[Pro\] - how many displays, what resolution/frequency?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335322/macbook-pro-how-many-displays-what-resolution-frequency) That Macbook doesn't support 4k monitors.

Comment: Yes, but should work in 2K resolution? It works sometimes, but not consistently.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the monitor is working correctly?  Try with a different computer  Also, which model LG monitor are you using?

Comment: @Allan yes, monitor works fine with my other laptop. Thinkpad x260 over same mini display port.

Comment: Have you tried with another cable?