# M1 Pro, will two external monitors work?

Tags: display, thunderbolt, apple-silicon

I am considering getting a 14" M1 Pro Macbook and am a bit concerned whether my existing setup will work. That's what I've got:

- an Early2015 13" MB
- Apple thunderbolt display via Thunderbolt
- second monitor via HDMI
- ethernet via a Thunderbolt-Ethernet dongle
- USB A keyboard and mouse connected to the Display

Will everything work, especially two external monitors? What dongles/adapters/docks am I going to need?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacBook \[Pro\] - how many displays, what resolution/frequency?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335322/macbook-pro-how-many-displays-what-resolution-frequency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This should work, but you need some adapters.**

- How many displays can you connect to the MBP with an M1 Pro CPU?

A M1Pro machine can support up to two external screens with each up to a 6K resolution as per [Apples spec sheet](https://www.apple.com/de/macbook-pro-14-and-16/specs/).

---

- What dongles do you need?

The old 2015 MBP has Thunderbolt 2 (TB2) ports, the new MBPs (14" and 16") from 2021 only have TB3/TB4, HDMI, audio and SD-card (also MagSafe 3 but thats just for power). The TB2 connector is different from the TB3/TB4 connector, so you need an adapter for the Apple Thunderbolt Display (ADT), e.g. [this one from Apple](https://www.apple.com/de/shop/product/MMEL2ZM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb%E2%80%91c-auf-thunderbolt-2-adapter?fnode=d20d1479a7b224a40eb0a9447192dfa2457362e040d117a0f78527ecad15575089fd138412688979fd2d356319439a3f3907230a187671d93ba679360949e6e63c2d9b1072329eac64cb732e104b1b341758f6b1ec2a9ee68b52ff8751050be8). The monitor connected via HDMI will work the same, you simply plug it into your new machine and there you go. For the Thunderbolt-Ethernet Adapter you will need a new one as well, you can basically buy any USB-C/TB3/TB4 to Ethernet adapter.