# How many monitors can my 27" 2019 iMac support?

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, hdmi

I've got a 2019, 27" iMac Retina 5k with 8GB RAM and a Radeon Pro 570x with 4GB RAM.

Currently, I've got two Thunderbolt 3 -> HDMI adapters plugged in, and I'm running those to TVs at 720p resolution for audience & stage displays.

With all the software I'm running for our live streaming, I'd like an extra monitor or two for extra real estate for me as the "producer". Can I use a Thunderbolt 3 dock with 3 TB3/HDMI/DP outputs (assuming I can find such a thing) to be able to run 4 *external* monitors (3 from the dock, one direct from the iMac), in addition to the built-in display where *all the external monitors are at **1080P or lower***?

I've found a lot of questions about plugging in 4k or higher external monitors, and loads about different configurations/ages of iMac, but I know little enough about the Mac world in general to know how well those would apply to my particular set up. If this is a duplicate question here, my apologies, nothing came up in the "similar questions" box.

At the link provided by Tetsujin, it says:

> All "Mid-2017" and "2019" iMac models, regardless of display size, support one 5120x2880 (5K) external display at 60 Hz with support for one billion colors; two 3840x2160 (4K UHD) external displays at 60 Hz with support for one billion colors; or two 4096x2304 (4K) external displays at 60 Hz with support for millions of colors.

My question is can it support more external monitors if the resolution is *lower* than 4K, though I'm getting the impression that the answer is "no".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacBook \[Pro\] - how many displays, what resolution/frequency?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335322/macbook-pro-how-many-displays-what-resolution-frequency) [I only just added iMac to the title to make it easier to google]

Comment: Not explicitly, @Tetsujin. That's all the info I've found anywhere. My question, now updated, wasn't explicit enough - does it matter if the external monitors are _lower_ resolution than 4K. Though I presume the answer is still "no".

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if it could run more displays at lower res, it would say so. I can't check any of this info, but EveryMac are usually very well researched, including info sometimes added by private individuals, not just Apple's own official spec.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't see anything there indicating that more was possible, so I'll just assume the answer is "No", and we'll have to look at other possibilities.